# Пропадает рекламный баннер AdMob в игре Unity при сварачивании игры

Tags: android, unity3d-android, admob

Использую версию плагина admob 8.5.3 в unity. После билда проекта всё нормально работает на телефоне, но когда выхожу из игры оставляя его в активных задачах, и захожу обратно то баннер не отображается. Попробовал заново загрузить банер после захода в игру, но не работает.